# How to test a BigCommerce app or plugin before submission

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there any way to test your app or plugin before submitting for approval?
Or is there any sandbox for BigCommerce to test the apps prior?

How were the developers of the apps that are presently in the BigCommerce store able to test during the development phase?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can test your app in a free trial store.

You can do this by:

1. Setting up a developer account
2. Logging in to the Apps section
3. Adding a draft app
4. Logging in to any Bigcommerce store (preferably a trial store) where you are an admin
5. Go to Apps then My Drafts
6. Install your app & test away

See https://developer.bigcommerce.com for more info.

Comment: But I don't have https urls for auth ,load and uninstall callbacks right now, is there any way we can host(with https urls) our code to test the app.

Comment: Those URLs and https are necessary for full testing. Otherwise you can do unit testing and use dummy data to simulate the data returned from a store.

Comment: Great answer. SSL(HTTPS) is needed to test out OAuth and webhooks. (though you can get away with a self-signed cert). You will need a valid SSL for receiving notifications from the created webhooks though.

Comment: I don't think this should be the case: if a localhost is specified in the callbacks for a draft app (or any URL really) this is clearly being used in a testing mode, so should the SSL restriction really be enforced?

Comment: I think there should be a workaround for testing. It would make it much easier to not require SSL while in draft mode, but then someone would surely publish without fixing causing issues.... Regardless of what should be, this is the reality we work with.

Comment: I think only 'owner' can add the draft app.  I'm working for a client, and she gave me 'admin' rights but I couldn't add my draft app to her shop for testing.  this is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

To test your app on local, use ngrok.io to create a https url that tunnels to your localhost

Comment: Yes, either use this OR you can use heroku for deploying your app for free!